# Remove border around the tabs in TabControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, border, tabcontrol, appearance

When you create a TabControl, you always have an ugly 2 pixel (or so) big white border around it. I wasn't able to find to way to remove it. TabControl doesn't have a BorderStyle.

This is most annoying for a media player where everything around the video has to be black. But instead you have those ugly white borders around the tabs.

Suggestions? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Comment: `Suggestions?` - Yes. Use relevant windows UI technologies (any of the XAML-based) and forget winforms forever.

Comment: Check "Buttons" or "FlatButtons" for the Appearence property of the tab control. Or you could draw your own tab control by selecting "OwnerDrawFixed" for the DrawMode property ([OwnerDrawFixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.drawmode.aspx))